# Domain Modeling question / collections with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, domain-model

Please consider the domain model shown below (simplified for brevity - no ids etc.)  A `Customer` can comment on a `Product` only once.  Lets assume (for reasons I don't want to get into here) that the `Customer` class cannot have a collection of `Review`s that it owns.  The `Product` is the main Aggregate root here.

Often in this situation, when retrieving the `Product`, it will only be in the context of a particular `Customer`.  In other words I will only be interested in the members of the `Reviews` collection that belong to that particular `Customer`.

So, it there a way, when retrieving the `Product` object, of restricting the population of the collection to the review that relates to the `Customer` I supply?  How would this be implemented in NHibernate?  Is this at all consistent with NHibernate best practices (and to a lesser degree DDD)?

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Review> Reviews{ get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Reviews= new HashedSet<Review>();
    }
}

public class Review
{
    public virtual string ReviewText { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Reviewer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This can be done using NHibernate's filtering capabilities; see [this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/04/nhibernate-filters.aspx) for a full discussion.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll take a read.